# regex how to match whole words

Tags: regex

How do you match whole words using a regular expression? And by words, I don't mean words with just alphabets, they could be anything. Like this sentence:

```
The r-a-i-n i~n S@#p=ain s\t*ays m-a-i-n-l-y i<>n t;he p|lai5n.
```

I'm trying to match and get each word that's separated by a space (regardless of what that word may contain), by [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZI1jNB/2/) seems to be picking up each and every alphabet in the string. How can I get it to match each word?

I'm trying to get a match like this:

`The` `r-a-i-n` `i~n` `S@#p=ain` `s\t*ays` `m-a-i-n-l-y` `i<>n` `t;he` `p|lai5n.`

Comment: You can use `\S+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZI1jNB/3)).

Comment: Yes. That's what I was trying to do?